# gl_VertexID values when calling glDrawElements

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl, vertex-buffer

I am struggling a bit to understand the values that `gl_VertexID` primitive contains when the vertex shader is executed.

I have the standard modern rendering pipeline, in which after setting up shaders, buffers, etc I call the code below to render a mesh

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, auxMesh->indicesBuffer);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, auxMesh->numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

In the vertex shader I want to manually access to the current vertex being rendered retrieving it from the original buffer (I know this sounds nonsense, but I need to do this for a reason), therefore I pass the vertex buffer as the texture buffer `u_tbo_tex` and I access to the actual coordinates as follows:

```
vec3 vertex_1 = texelFetch(u_tbo_tex, gl_VertexID + 0).xyz;
vec3 vertex_2 = texelFetch(u_tbo_tex, gl_VertexID + 1).xyz; 
vec3 vertex_3 = texelFetch(u_tbo_tex, gl_VertexID + 2).xyz;
```

And the values of these vertex `vertex_1`, `vertex_2`, `vertex_3` make perfect sense.

However, I can't really understand what values `gl_VertexID` got in each iteration. Is `gl_VertexID` sequentially assigned following the range of `[0...auxMesh->numIndices]`.  Or are the values increased `+3` at every iteration because I am drawing triangles?

I need to understand this because I am interested in calling `textureFetch(u_tbo_tex, i)` where `i` is a arbitrary triangle in my mesh (or whatever `i` needs to be to access an arbitrary triangle), but I can't find the right way to access to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`gl_VertexID`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/gl_VertexID.xhtml) is the literal index value of the vertex that is being processed.

In the case of non-indexed geometry an implicit increasing index were assigned to each vertex being processed.

The Vertex Shader runs on individual vertices without knowledge of adjacency or the kind of primitive being processed. If you're using indexed geometry, a shared vertex will likely be processed fewer times than it's used.

As a tangent, Geometry Shaders have, given the right primitive type, some knowledge of adjacency but probably not enough to solve the problem at hand.

If you wish to identify the triangle you're in, consider using unindexed geometry as the mapping to triangle ID and vertex ID is a matter of division and modulo by 3.

Edit: removed term "vertex processing" which has wider meaning and mentioned GS

Comment: **+1**: However, it is not *"as if"*, that is *literally* what happens. Each drawn vertex is assigned an incremental `gl_VertexID` (assuming it is not a strip/fan, because they do funny things to the vertex stream by referencing previous vertices). I do have a minor fuss regarding the last thing you wrote though: ***vertex processing*** actually includes primitive assembly (Geometry Shaders), which ***does*** have knowledge of adjacent vertices given the proper primitive type. This answer works best if you ignore Geometry Shaders or restrict "vertex processing" to vertex shading ;)